# iOS 6 MapKit Drawing (realtime) traveled distance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, gps, ios6

i want to implement user tracking (running, walking) with GPS (Apple Maps). So when user is walking i want to draw a line on map - realtime.

How can I do that?

I saw one solution here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial but it works only if you have already point A and B.

Thanks in advance!

Tom

Answer (score 3):

For the first step i prepare the property like this

```
ViewController.h

    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView *mapView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MKPolyline* routeLine;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MKPolylineView* routeLineView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *trackPointArray;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    @property (nonatomic, readwrite) MKMapRect routeRect;

    @end
```

then i'm implement like this inside `ViewController.m`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    MKMapPoint * pointsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*2);
    pointsArray[0]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(oldLocation.coordinate);
    pointsArray[1]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(tempNewLocation.coordinate);

    routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:2];
    free(pointsArray);

     if (tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude - oldLocation.coordinate.latitude < 1)
     {
          [[self mapView] addOverlay:routeLine];
     }

}
```

For iOS6 you could try this way instead of the code above :

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:locations.count - 1];
    CLLocation *oldLocation = nil;
    if (locations.count > 1)
    {
        oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:locations.count - 2];
    }

    MKMapPoint * pointsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*2);
    pointsArray[0]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(oldLocation.coordinate);
    pointsArray[1]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(tempNewLocation.coordinate);

    routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:2];
    free(pointsArray);

    if (tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude - oldLocation.coordinate.latitude < 1)
    {
        [[self mapView] addOverlay:routeLine];
    }
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;
    self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:[self routeLine]];
    [[self routeLineView] setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:167/255.0f green:210/255.0f blue:244/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [[self routeLineView] setStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:106/255.0f green:151/255.0f blue:232/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [[self routeLineView] setLineWidth:15.0];
    [[self routeLineView] setLineCap:kCGLineCapRound];
    overlayView = [self routeLineView];
    return overlayView;
}
```

i hope my answer will help you, Cheers.

Comment: Your answer is really great, but in iOS 6+ `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` is deprecated. Instead iOS 6+ uses a method that only gives one set of coordinates as the location updates. How would we go about doing this for newer version of iOS 6?

Comment: Hello RazorSharp, Let check out my edith answer. hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! It looks like something is a little off though, the `oldLocation` coordinates never get set because `if (locations.count > 1)` is never a true statement with the new iOS 6+ method. The `locations` array / object only contains one location at a time in the array, not multiple. For this code to work, there would need to be some sort of logic to check if the new coordinate from `locations` is the same as the `newLocation` variable.